# Unable to pass my array of numbers into another class

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to compare two different arrays in different classes, one that is filled with user inputted numbers and the other one at random. But I cannot get the one that was filled with numbers from the user to go into my constructor class to compare them.
Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LotteryTester{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] Picks = new int [5];
        System.out.println("Introduce your numbers here: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < Picks.length; i++)
        {
            Picks[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Picks.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Picks); 
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class that is unable to find the first array:

```
import java.util.Random;
    public class Lottery
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int number;
        int count;
    public Lottery( )
    {
        int lotteryNums[] = new int[5];
        for (int i=0; i < lotteryNums.length; i++)
        {
            number = random.nextInt(10);
            lotteryNums[i] = number;
        }
    }

    public static int CompareNums(Picks[] numbers)
    {
        for (int i=0; i <Picks.length; i++)
        {
            if (Picks[i] == lotteryNums[i])
            {
                System.out.println("The number on " + (i+1)+ " matches");
                count++;
            }
            else 
            {
                   System.out.println("the number on " + (i+1)+ " matches");
                }
           }
           return count;
      }
}
```

I just don't get how to use methods properly

Comment: Where are you calling `Lottery.CompareNums()`?

Comment: I actually didn't know I was supposed to call the object, I assumed by using the same object name it referenced it.

Comment: You have to call the method for it to be run. Your main method currently does not call it.

Comment: Axel, you should start following a [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). It will help make your code much more readable. This will make your code easier to debug, and easier to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never assigning lotteryNums to a variable outside of the constructor. Whenever a method ends, all variables that were declared inside them are no longer accessible.

Your class should look like:

```
public class Lottery
{
   Random random = new Random();
   int number;
   int count;
   int lotteryNums[];
    public Lottery()
    {
        lotteryNums[] = new int[5]; //Set the variable in the class so we can use it later
        for (int i=0; i < lotteryNums.length; i++)
        {
            number = random.nextInt(10);
            lotteryNums[i] = number;
        }
    }

    public int CompareNums(Picks[] numbers) //Removed static since numbers are made in a constructor. All non-static class variables wouldn't be accessible otherwise.
    {
        for (int i=0; i <Picks.length; i++)
        {
            if (Picks[i] == lotteryNums[i])
            {
                System.out.println("The number on " + (i+1)+ " matches");
                count++;
            }
            else 
            {
               System.out.println("the number on " + (i+1)+ " matches");
            }
       }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Your main method can then be changed to follow the following logic.
Generate the winning numbers:

```
Lottery lottery = new Lottery();
```

Then, ask user for their numbers.
Finally, check the numbers against the winning numbers and see if user won.

```
if (lottery.CompareNums(lotteryNums) == 5) System.out.println("You Won!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can actually do this without an extra class, and arrayLists would be better.

Try this, I left comments to show you what I did.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CompareArrayLists {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<Integer> userNums = new ArrayList();
       ArrayList<Integer> randNums = new ArrayList();
       Random random = new Random();

       Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
       int num = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //let a user enter 5 numbers and generate 5 at the same time
       {
           System.out.print("Please enter your " + (i+1) + " number >");
           num = cin.nextInt();
           userNums.add(num);
           num = random.nextInt(10);
           randNums.add(num);
       }
       num = 0;
       for (int j : userNums)//test each item in userNums to see if matches in randNums
       {
           if (!(randNums.contains(j)))
               num++;//increment nums if something doesn't match
       }
       if (num > 0)//not a match if nums increments, you could also print nums to see how many are correct
          System.out.println("Not a match");
       else
          System.out.println("a match");



    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to do it in the same class without almost any problem, but I'm trying to learn how to do it in separate classes in order to get the gist of method calling but I just don't seem to understand how to call a method